# asp.net image controll not refresh image

Tags: asp.net

i write this code:

```
string url;
url=Server.MapPath("ImageTest/");
Image1.ImageUrl = "/ImageTest/2.jpg";
```

this code show my image file into my project root "ImagetTest" Folder,but when i change file in root folder,image controll show previous image!

For Example:i have "2.jpg" and "3.jpg" in root folder,run the project and click the button and show "2.jpg",greate!,Now i replace "2.jpg" and "3.jpg" file,Rename "3.jpg" to "2.jpg" and "2.jpg" to "3.jpg" So i click button but show previous picture "2.jpg" not "3.jpg" picture,when stop vs 2013 and reOpen project Solve it! and show new picture "3.jpg".

I Use this code:

```
yourPage.Response.Cache.SetNoServerCaching()
yourPage.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(System.Web.HttpCacheability.NoCache)
yourPage.Response.Cache.SetNoStore()
yourPage.Response.Cache.SetExpires(New DateTime(1900, 1, 1))
```

But Not Work!

My Compiler:vs2013 c# .net 4.0

How can i solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
Image1.ImageUrl = "/ImageTest/2.jpg"+"?"+DateTime.Now.Ticks;
```

Comment: No. it will tell your browser : you dont have the pic. I have it.

Comment: thanks man! i change code to do this:Image1.ImageUrl = "/ImageTest/2.jpg?"+DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString(); and work it.